# height issue in bootstrap switch

Tags: bootstrap-switch

[Bootstrap switch with on text 'Yes'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ylgy.png)

I am facing the problem with height in Bootstrap switch. I am not able to change the height of the switch. How can I change the height of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Just add following css to your page and adjust height, padding and margin according your design.

```
div.bootstrap-switch-container {
    height: 25px;
}
.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on, .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off, .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-label  {
    padding: 3px 12px;
}
div.bootstrap-switch {
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```